# ARKit and SwiftUI - Performance Overlay Issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, arkit

I'm trying to get started with ARKit in SwiftUI. But I'm unable to turn off this text that appears over the View. Does anyone know what the name of this text is and how I can toggle it off? It doesn't appear to be part of debug options and is a separate statistical output from SceneView's showStatistics boolean.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import ARKit

struct ARKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let session = ARSession()
    let sceneView = ARSCNView()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARSCNView {
        sceneView.delegate = context.coordinator
        sceneView.showsStatistics = false
        sceneView.debugOptions = []
        sceneView.session = session

        // Create a cube and add it to the scene
        let cube = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
        let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cube)
        cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.5)
        // Apply a 45-degree rotation around the Y-axis (in radians)
         let angle = 45.0 * .pi / 180.0
         cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, angle, 0)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
     
      return sceneView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARSCNView, context: Context) {
        // Update your AR scene here
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate {
        var parent: ARKitView
        
        init(_ parent: ARKitView) {
            self.parent = parent
          
        }
        
        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

           if let currentFrame = parent.sceneView.session.currentFrame {
               // Process the pixel data here
            }
        }
        

    }
}
```